# Editing Closed Won Opportunity Line Items?

Tags: permissions, user-profile

I am trying to modify Opportunity Line Items of a Closed Won Opportunity.

When I am using an user with System Administrator profile, it allows me to edit as well as delete opportunity line items without any issue.

Now, I need to provide opportunity line items' modification rights to another profile. Basically, its a higher Manager's profile who wants to adjust product quantity or price after it gets Closed Won.

I have already went to profile settings and gave read, write, delete permissions for Opportunity object.

But, it still doesn't allow that user to edit or delete the opportunity line items.

It keeps showing me following errors:

```
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
• Error 0014 - Can't modify products if Closed Won. Please ask your manager for assistance.

• Error 0023 - Please confirm if this is a test opportunity or not by choosing "yes" or "no" in the "Test Opportunity" field.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not salesforce.com standard errors (normal errors do not include an error code like that). You would need to figure out where the errors are being reported from (e.g. trigger, validation rule) to determine the appropriate permission to give the user. If your organization has documentation, please refer to that documentation, as the error codes should make it easy to search for how to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have searched the error, its coming from a validation rule on Opportunity. Thanks

Comment: @FarjadHasan Glad I could help!